# Is it possible to mirror the Net label in Altium 20.1.12?

Tags: altium, properties

The x and y hotkeys work for other components, but not the net label, which according to the 17.1 and 20.2 official website guide should work. I've also gone into the properties tab of the net label, but the only thing I can do is rotate, which will make the letters upside down.

Here are the links for the websites I looked at: [17.1](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/sch-obj-netlabelnet-label-ad?version=17.1#:%7E:text=Press%20the%20X%20or%20Y%20keys%20to%20flip,right-click%20or%20press%20Esc%20to%20exit%20placement%20mode.) and [20.2](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/sch-obj-netlabelnet-label-ad)

Update: the properties in the netlabel allow for mirroring, I just didn't see an actual mirror button that is present in other components. You have to manually mirror it, but hotkeys still don't work which honestly isn't a problem.

Comment: Have you tried Altium support forum (there's one that uses discord).

Comment: Yeah I suppose I should have tried that first.